# Color state is changing when I am deleting item from list and do setState((){})

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I am assigning random color to a ListTile leading property in flutter, but when I am deleting a item using setState, color of all list items are changing, I tried to use ObjectKey() , I want to keep the color state constant

```
         ListTile(
              key: ObjectKey(expense),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                 _allExpenses.remove(expense);
                });
              },
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20,
                backgroundColor: Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)),
                child: FindIcon(expense.type),
              ),
              title: Text("Test"),
            )
```

I am using provider and notifyListeners(); which make rebuild of the UI on every item delete

Comment: you set the color inside the build method and setstate will rebuild it.

Comment: are you still getting the same error on removing this line `key: ObjectKey(expense),`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the `setState` will rebuild every time. If you want to work with `key`s, a new wrapper of `ListTile` must be created.

But, there is another alternative. In the `initState`, a list of random colors can be created:

```dart
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyList({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  final List<int> _allExpenses = [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 22];
  
  List<Color> _colors;
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _colors = [
      for(final _ in _allExpenses)
        Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)),
    ];
  }
  
  void removeOne(int index){
    setState(() {
       _allExpenses.removeAt(index);
      _colors.removeAt(index);
    });
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        for(int i = 0; i < _allExpenses.length; i++)
          ListTile(
            //key: ObjectKey(expense),
            onTap: () => removeOne(i),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 20,
              backgroundColor: _colors[i],
              child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
            title: Text("Test ${_allExpenses[i]}"),
          ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

That is a good alternative because you can control the needed memory for those random colors. That logic can be extended to `ChangeNotifier`s with their `notifyListeners()` using the `addListener()` in the `initState`:

```dart
@override initState(){
  ...
  myChangeNotifierList.addListener(() => setState((){}));
}
```

There is another alternative where you delegate the responsibility of handling the random color and keeping the state of each list tile.

```dart
class MyListWithKeys extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyListWithKeys({ Key key }):  super(key: key);


  @override
  _MyListWithKeysState createState() => _MyListWithKeysState();
}

class _MyListWithKeysState extends State<MyListWithKeys> {
  final List<int> _allExpenses = [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 22];
  
  void removeOne(int expense){
    setState(() {
       _allExpenses.remove(expense);
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        for(final expense in _allExpenses)
          MyTile(
            key: ObjectKey(expense),
            expense: expense,
            onTap: () => removeOne(expense),
          ),
      ]
    );
  }
}

class MyTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.expense,
    @required this.onTap,
  }) : assert(expense != null),
       assert(onTap != null),
       super(key: key);
  
  final int expense;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  _MyTileState createState() => _MyTileState();
}

class _MyTileState extends State<MyTile> {
  Color _color;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _color = Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 20,
        backgroundColor: _color,
        child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      ),
      title: Text('Test ${widget.expense}'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank , thankyou for your answer, but I forgot to tell that my remove and edit method has notifyListeners(); which make rebuild of the UI on every item delete/edit , so even if I use initState it will change the color, so for this I need to save color in object when I create a new instance of Expense Class, please let me if you have other workaround , without saving color data

Comment: @MrudulAddipalli I edited the answer adding a solution with `ObjectKey` creating a Stateful list tile that handles the random color.

Comment: Morena, actually , when I delete/edit expense then , due to notifyListerners() my ListView builder which is in build method get re executed to build my statefull ListTile , where initState is reexecuted, and thus color get's changed on each screen rebuild

Comment: You can follow the last strategy. It is necessary to create a custom stateful list tile to keep the random color only once in its `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Random()` in the `initState` so that its not called again when you do a `setState`.

```
    Color bgColor;
    
    @override
    void initState(){
     super.initState()
     bgColor = Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff));
    }
```

and your `ListTile`

```
    ListTile(
    
            key: ObjectKey(expense),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                 _allExpenses.remove(expense);
                });
              },
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20,
                backgroundColor: bgColor,
                child: FindIcon(expense.type),
              ),
              title: Text("Test"),
            )
```

Comment: Hi Calvin , thankyou for your answer, but I forgot to tell that my remove and edit method has notifyListeners(); which make rebuild of the UI on every item delete/edit , so even if I use initState it will change the color, so for this I need to save color in object when I create a new instance of Expense Class, please let me if you have other workaround , without saving color data